# Jupyter Lab - Unable to Open Windows OneDrive Directory

Tags: python-3.x, windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

This has been driving me crazy for over a year. Basically have Python 3.11 installed on a Windows 10 machine. Company has OneDrive syncing running on the machine, so Jupyter Lab files are saved in Windows/ OneDrive folders. I will create a folder and use it to save data and Jupyter Lab for a period of time. Then "something happens" and I am no longer able to access the folder through the Jupyter Lab browser interface. I can access through Windows Explorer etc, but when I try to access and view in Jupyter Lab, it throws the error noted below. I can move folder contents to a new folder and everything will work for a period of time, then something happens and I get the error again.

Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?
Any settings I could change?
Any suggested fixes?

Not sure what to trouble should/ look.

Any help would be appreciated.

Jupyter Lab - 3.6.3
Python - 3.11
Windows 10 - 10.0.19045
OneDrive - Build 23.101.0514.0004
Chrome - 116.0.5845.188

-------------- Error Log -----------------------

```
To access the server, open this file in a browser:
    file:///C:/Users/user1234/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-19500-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/lab?token=43e123456e503de90628c8c74ff16eb5a2e4c96d3d21dd0
    http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=43e123456e503de90628c8c74ff16eb5a2e4c96d3d21dd0
```

0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[W 2023-09-14 12:15:53.418 LabApp] Could not determine jupyterlab build status without nodejs
[E 2023-09-14 12:16:10.988 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents/OneDrive%20-%20Company/new_jupyter/mbm_it_time_tracking_mirgation_2?content=1&1694708170983 (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/contents/OneDrive%20-%20Company/new_jupyter/mbm_it_time_tracking_mirgation_2?content=1&1694708170983', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1769, in *execute
result = await result
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\contents\handlers.py", line 121, in get
model = await ensure_async(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\utils_*init**.py", line 182, in ensure_async
result = await obj
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 887, in get
model = await self._dir_model(path, content=content)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 754, in _dir_model
dir_contents = await run_sync(os.listdir, os_dir)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
return await future
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
result = context.run(func, *args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'c:\Users\user1234\OneDrive - Company\new_jupyter\mbm_it_time_tracking_mirgation_2'
[W 2023-09-14 12:16:10.995 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Unhandled error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1769, in *execute
result = await result
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\contents\handlers.py", line 121, in get
model = await ensure_async(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\utils_*init**.py", line 182, in ensure_async
result = await obj
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 887, in get
model = await self._dir_model(path, content=content)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 754, in _dir_model
dir_contents = await run_sync(os.listdir, os_dir)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
return await future
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\user1234\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\anyio_backends_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
result = context.run(func, *args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'c:\Users\user1234\OneDrive - Company\new_jupyter\mbm_it_time_tracking_mirgation_2'
[E 2023-09-14 12:16:10.999 ServerApp] {
"Host": "localhost:8888",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
[E 2023-09-14 12:16:11.013 ServerApp] 500 GET /api/contents/OneDrive%20-%20Company/new_jupyter/mbm_it_time_tracking_mirgation_2?content=1&1694708170983 (86a3026ace8a4fd995b0658528bbc2e9@::1) 14.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-unable-to-open-windows-onedrive-directory/21442?u=fomightez) without acknowledgment.    
Those interested should also check there.

Comment: I have a very close issue on MacOS. The error is "[Errno 31] Too many links" when I want to overwrite some sync file. But I am in a  "Always Keep on This device" folder and Ondrive is online or not open or paused : same behaviour for some random files. It is CRAZY !!! and i happened recently : last month. I work on VSCode/ Jupiterlab 3.5.3 / Notebook 6.5.2, MacOS Monterey.

Comment: Finally, I think it is a onedrive issue : Although I have enabled  "Always Keep on This device", the files are not "Downloaded" for OneDrive point of view. I still have a check lettle icon on file and at the same time a cloud with an arrow in the lower part icon meaning it is not downloaded. I don't know at all why ! And when I want to copy/edit/open a file like that, I can't : onedrive says that I can't open / copy because not downloaded ! But I have never asked to clear the cache files ! maybe the last Onedrive app udpate (23.204.xxx / 11th October) is the issue...